# Can you pass a link to the update availability checker to check if the in-app update function is working well?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, updates, auto-update

I'm trying to implement the in-app updates on a new App I just created on Android Studio for testing. The app is just a "hello world" but I implemented the in-app updates checker as it says in these two pages:

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates#kotlin

https://johncodeos.com/how-to-implement-in-app-updates-in-android-using-kotlin/

We're using Google play for work (or the actual name for a "private acces" play store) where we upload our business App's, and these Apps are only for employees to use in stores. But even so, this Apps have a link, same as normal ones (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=country.company.appname.something)

I think I understand how it works (more or less) but before uploading the app I want to check directly with another app link if it works.

My question is if I can use one of this links of one of our Apps (on a phone with acces and already configured, of course) to check if the update availability checker works or if I can only use it on the new App I'm doing and hence I need to upload it and do all the process with this "test" App

I put here the code so you can see it. Some snackbars are just for tracing the flow of the code.

UpdateInApp.kt class:

```
package com.example.demoinappupdates

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManager
import com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateManagerFactory
import com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallState
import com.google.android.play.core.install.InstallStateUpdatedListener
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.AppUpdateType
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.InstallStatus
import com.google.android.play.core.install.model.UpdateAvailability

class UpdateInApp(activity: Activity) : InstallStateUpdatedListener {

    private var appUpdateManager: AppUpdateManager
    private val MY_REQUEST_CODE = 500
    private var parentActivity: Activity = activity

    private var currentType = AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE

    init {
        appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(parentActivity)
        appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { info ->
            // Check if update is available

            Snackbar.make(
                    parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
                    "Aquí, en el init, entra",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()

            if (info.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) { // UPDATE IS AVAILABLE
                if (info.updatePriority() == 5) { // Priority: 5 (Immediate update flow)
                    if (info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                    }
                } else if (info.updatePriority() == 4) { // Priority: 4
                    val clientVersionStalenessDays = info.clientVersionStalenessDays()
                    if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 5 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                        // Trigger IMMEDIATE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                    } else if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 3 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                        // Trigger FLEXIBLE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
                    }
                } else if (info.updatePriority() == 3) { // Priority: 3
                    val clientVersionStalenessDays = info.clientVersionStalenessDays()
                    if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 30 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                        // Trigger IMMEDIATE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                    } else if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 15 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                        // Trigger FLEXIBLE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
                    }
                } else if (info.updatePriority() == 2) { // Priority: 2
                    val clientVersionStalenessDays = info.clientVersionStalenessDays()
                    if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 90 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)) {
                        // Trigger IMMEDIATE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                    } else if (clientVersionStalenessDays != null && clientVersionStalenessDays >= 30 && info.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)) {
                        // Trigger FLEXIBLE flow
                        startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
                    }
                } else if (info.updatePriority() == 1) { // Priority: 1
                    // Trigger FLEXIBLE flow
                    startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE)
                } else { // Priority: 0
                    // Do not show in-app update
                }
            } else {
                // UPDATE IS NOT AVAILABLE
               /* Snackbar.make(
                        parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
                        "El Snakcbar de prueba",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show() */
            }
        }
        appUpdateManager.registerListener(this)
    }


    private fun startUpdate(info: AppUpdateInfo, type: Int) {
        appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(info, type, parentActivity, MY_REQUEST_CODE)
        currentType = type

        /* Snackbar.make(
                parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
                "startupdate entra",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show() */
    }

    fun onResume() {
        Snackbar.make(
                parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
                "El Snakcbar de onresume",
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ejej"){}.show()

        appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener { info ->
            if (currentType == AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE) {
                // If the update is downloaded but not installed, notify the user to complete the update.
                if (info.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED)
                    flexibleUpdateDownloadCompleted()
            } else if (currentType == AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE) {
                // for AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE only, already executing updater
                if (info.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.DEVELOPER_TRIGGERED_UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
                    startUpdate(info, AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode != AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                // If the update is cancelled or fails, you can request to start the update again.
                Log.e("ERROR", "Update flow failed! Result code: $resultCode")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun flexibleUpdateDownloadCompleted() {
        Snackbar.make(
            parentActivity.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
            "An update has just been downloaded.",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
        ).apply {
            setAction("RESTART") { appUpdateManager.completeUpdate() }
            setActionTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            show()
        }
    }

    fun onDestroy() {
        appUpdateManager.unregisterListener(this)
    }

    override fun onStateUpdate(state: InstallState) {
        if (state.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
            flexibleUpdateDownloadCompleted()
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt class

```
package com.example.demoinappupdates

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var inAppUpdate: UpdateInApp

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        inAppUpdate = UpdateInApp(this)
       /* Snackbar.make(
            this.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_layout),
            "El Snakcbar de prueba",
            Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show()*/
    }
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        inAppUpdate.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        inAppUpdate.onResume()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        inAppUpdate.onDestroy()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible, since what I'm trying to do could only be done changing the Bundle ID, and that would cause some compatibility issues based on more than just one app sharing the same one.

For the record, when I refer to the Bundle ID I mean `applicationId` on the build.gradle file.